# Get data from code.hs with calling function(argument)

Tags: google-apps-script

I have index.html given below

```
<select id="id">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select> 

document.getElementById("id").onchange = function(){
  let id = this.value
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(setData).getData(id)
}

function setData(data) {
  console.log(data)
}
```

And code.gs given below

```
function getData() {
  var data = cleanRange(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Продажи").getRange("A2:K2").getValues(), id)
  return data
}

function cleanRange(range, id){
  var filtered = range.filter(function (el) {
    return el[5] === id;
  });
  return filtered;
}
```

How can i call function getData from index.html with an argument.

Comment: As long as none of the data is [restricted](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values) you can use google.script.run as you apparentsly already know.  I'd put them both into one object and return it to the success handler.

Comment: I can't add to one object, because the id is passed to code.gs for filtering

Comment: Really? How about `cleanRange({data:range,id:id});`

Comment: @Cooper, You did not understand me, the data array comes as a response to the request back to index.html

Comment: Does getData() have a parameter id in your code? Is this the correct way to call the function `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(setData).getData(id)`?

Comment: @JoseVasquez, idk, so i asked

Answer (score 0):

I did it with the following code, because I realized that the above option would not work.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="id>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
    </select>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("id").onchange = function(){
      let id = this.value;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getData).setId(id)
    }

    function getData(){
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(setData).getData()
    }

    function setData(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function getData(){
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Продажи").getRange("D2:K").getValues();
  var id = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("orderNumber"); 
  var result = cleanRange(data, id)
  console.log(result)
  return result; 
}

function setId(id){
   PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("orderNumber", id);
}

function cleanRange(range, id){
  var filtered = range.filter(function (el) {
    return el[2] == id;
  });
  return filtered;
}
```